# Compare today with some value passed from front end

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008

I need to compare current day with some value. Like from front end I am passing `5`, then in `t-sql` I want to match if the current day of the month is `5`.

Comment: Not very clear what you want to do. So what if 5 is passed in and the current day of the month isn't 5? Why would your front end pass anything in at all?

Comment: Its requirement. But, anyways i got the answer. using DatePart()... thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can retrieve parts of the date with [DATEPART](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174420.aspx).

```
DATEPART ( datepart , date )

DATEPART( MM, GETDATE())
```

Should return an `INT` value of `3` for `March`.

Answer (score 0):

Well, just pass an `INT` parameter to your stored procedure (I'm assuming you're using this in a stored procedure?). Then you can do something like

```
IF DATEPART(dd, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) = @givenday ...
```

Does that help?